# Does The Witcher 2 download on Amazon activate on Steam?

Tags: steam, the-witcher-2

Does [this version of Witcher: Assassins of Kings](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0051BH6FK) activate on Steam?

I want to know before I buy it.

Answer (score 2):

[No,](http://www.gamespot.com/the-witcher-2-assassins-of-kings/forum/messages/platform/pc?topic_id=m-1-59343043&pid=975399) it is [not a Steamworks game](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110419154527AAZmR7N) (so it does not require Steam to play).  Games purchased at retail that do not require Steam can [generally](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-wusf-3601) not be activated on Steam.

You can add it to your games list through Steam, but it won't patch via Steam and you will be able to play it even if Steam is not loaded or offline.

The link you provided seems to be for an Amazon digital download, which contains [its own DRM scheme](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200205020&#drm).

Comment: Just to add, if you buy the standard edition of The Witcher 2, it won't come with any DRM at all anymore, it was patched out of the game with the first patch they released. You can get that version e.g. [at Good Old Games, which is owned by the same company as the studio that developed the Witcher 2](http://www.gog.com/en/gamecard/the_witcher_2/).